# how to use javascript for redirecting parent page with conditional alerts?

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm currently using this code:

```
var domains = ["domain.net", "domain.com", "domain.info"];

if (domains.indexOf(document.location.hostname) == -1 && document.cookie.indexOf('redirected=1') == -1)
{
    window.top.location="http://domain.net";
    document.cookie = "redirected=1";
alert("Redirecting to our main website");
}
else if (domains.indexOf(document.location.hostname) == 1)
{
    document.cookie = "redirected=1";
}
alert("Thanks for joining our main website");
```

if i move the second alert over "}" it will not give any alert, and when i leave it as it is i will get sequential alerts starting with 1st alert and then second alert, then when page redirects i will get second alert again.

is there a way to fix this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: indexOf is 0 indexed so by going to the main site you are setting the document.location.hostname = 0 not 1.

Comment: @JoshVillars, it didnt work

Comment: so you are trying to find out how to set a cookie when the page is redirected? Or are you trying to catch the event that you are on http://domain.net?

Comment: @JoshVillars, after it redirect from the other page i dont get the thanks alert.

Comment: @JoshVillars, to make it more clear, i want the 1st alert to show and after it redirect i want the second alert to show, and if opened the main site directly i want only the 2nd alert to show
thanks again and sorry for the trouble

Comment: @JoshVillars, i solved the issue thanks, solved by using `else {` only without anything else

Comment: no worries, as I said, since it's 0 indexed, you'll want the domains.indexOf(document.location.hostname)== 0 not 1 plus you may need to add `http://www.` to each domain in your array for it to compare correctly. 

The reason I asked why you wanted to catch that event was because you didn't use an else statement (which is much easier). No worries :)

Comment: @JoshVillars, now it's not 100% , if the cookie is not there and i open the main page it will also redirect me :)